# Grep for whole word that starts with X in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I need to blank-out certain words in various phrases, but because the words may be conjugated, plural, or possessive, I can only look for the first few letters. An example:

```
example = "You are the elephant's friend."
gsub("\\beleph.*\\b", " _____ " , example)
[1] "You are the  _____ "
```

How can I match the entire word from the first few letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gsub("\\beleph[[:alpha:][:punct:]]+\\b", "_____" , example)
[1] "You are the _____ friend."
```

works in this instance.

The change is replacing the greedy (and sometimes dangerous) ".*" matching anything and everything regex with the character class "[[:alpha:][:punct:]]+", which matches alphabetical characters and punctuation characters. See `help(regex)` for additional ready-made character classes that may be useful, like [:alnum:] in case any strings contain digits as well.

---

In order to catch matches with the first word as well, the following should work. Here's an example.

```
exampleYoda = "elephant's friend you be."

gsub("(\\b|^)eleph[[:alpha:][:punct:]]+\\b", "_____" , exampleYoda)
[1] "_____ friend you be."
```

which also works with example

```
gsub("(\\b|^)eleph[[:alpha:][:punct:]]+\\b", "_____" , example)
[1] "You are the _____ friend."
```

Comment: Does the ```\\b``` already take care of ending the word at a space?

Comment: From the help file in my post: "The symbol \b matches the empty string at either edge of a word." So it essentially matches up to the final character of a word, and does not include the space that separates words.

Comment: I've noticed this doesn't work for the first word in the phrase. Why is that?

Comment: Not entirely sure. But Maybe because the first position is typically accessed with the anchor, ^. I suspect that replacing \\b in the beginning of the regular expression with (^|\\b) will work. I've added an example to show it works.

Comment: exampleYoda worked but this doesn't: ```gsub("(^|\\b)You[[:alpha:][:punct:]]+\\b", "_____" , example)``` Confused am I.

Comment: Aha! It can't be the complete word. Okay well that presents an interesting problem for scalability, too. Fascinating.

Comment: OK. If you reverse the order (\\b|^), it will work in both instances. A bit beyond my depth.

Answer (score 3):

To make your original code work you just have to make the quantifier ungreedy.

```
example = "You are the elephant's friend."
gsub("\\beleph.*?\\b", " _____ " , example)
[1] "You are the  _____ 's friend."
```

This solution cause problems with the ' but you can use blank spaces insead, so you can try

```
example = "You are the elephant's friend."
gsub("\\seleph.*?\\s", " _____ " , example)
[1] "You are the _____ friend."
```